# opentelemetry в трейсах не отображает имя сервиса

Tags: spring-boot

Использую Spring boot 2.1.1, повысить версию не вариант. Трейсы отправляются, но имя сервиса - не отображается, в этом поле пишет: `unknown_service:java`
Вот все зависимости, связанные с otel

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-otlp</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opentelemetry.instrumentation</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentelemetry-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0-alpha</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>1.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Вот проперти, взятые из документации

```
otel.traces.exporter=otlp
otel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://otel.host:4317
otel.resourse.attribute=service.name=my_service_name

otel.service.name=my_service_name

logging.level.io.opentelemetry=DEBUG

spring.application.name=my_service_name
```

Для справки: `otel.service.name` и `otel.resourse.attribute` одновременно не использовался.
Конфигурации никакой дополнительной нет
Буду благодарен за ответы:)